# vagrant invalid option was specified

Tags: windows, command-line, vagrant, vagrant-windows

I am trying to install in on my laptop while running on Windows 8. I have downloaded and installed vagrant and Virtualbox  and currently am trying to download vagrant box using

```
vagrant init tsawler/wafs; vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

and i get this error,

```
C:\Users\patrick\Documents\website>vagrant init tsawler/wafs; vagrant up --provider virtualbox
An invalid option was specified. The help for this command is available below.

Usage: vagrant init [options] [name [url]]

Options:

    -f, --force                      Overwrite existing Vagrantfile
    -m, --minimal                    Create minimal Vagrantfile (no help comment
s)
        --output FILE                Output path for the box. '-' for stdout
    -h, --help                       Print this help
```

I have tried to add the `-f` or `--force` option after the init but still get the same result. Is there a setting that missing?

Comment: Can you try these commands separately ?

`C:\Users\patrick\Documents\website>vagrant init tsawler/wafs
C:\Users\patrick\Documents\website>vagrant up`

Comment: thanks alot vipinagg, this solved my problem, it installed perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, multiple commands on the same line may not get parsed correctly, and running them separately usually works. Try these.

`C:\Users\patrick\Documents\website>vagrant init tsawler/wafs C:\Users\patrick\Documents\website>vagrant up`

Answer (score 0):

Run command prompt with Administrative privileges.